# Error in VBA:`[Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am creating a macro to add data from my Excel sheet into my MySQL Database

But when I run the Macro I am getting Error:

`[Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`

**Code:**

```
Sub UpdateMySQLDatabasePHP()

' For detailed description visit http://www.vbaexcel.eu/

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = Range("e4").Value             ' IP number or servername
Database_Name = Range("e1").Value         ' Name of database
User_ID = Range("h1").Value                      'id user or username
Password = Range("e3").Value                    'Password
Tabellen = Range("e2").Value                     ' Name of table to write to

rad = 0
While Range("a6").Offset(rad, 0).Value <> tom
TextStrang = tom
kolumn = 0
While Range("A5").Offset(0, kolumn).Value <> tom
    If kolumn = 0 Then TextStrang = TextStrang & Cells(5, 1) & " = '" & Cells(6 + rad, 1)
    If kolumn <> 0 Then TextStrang = TextStrang & "', " & Cells(5, 1 + kolumn) & " = '" & Cells(6 + rad, 1 + kolumn)
    kolumn = kolumn + 1
Wend



TextStrang = TextStrang & "'"
field2 = "cid"
field1 = "bid"
table1 = "MMbanner"
SQLStr = "UPDATE " & Tabellen & " SET " & TextStrang & "WHERE " & Cells(5, 1) & " = '" & Cells(6 + rad, 1) & "'"
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

Cn.Execute SQLStr
rad = rad + 1
Wend
Set rs = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks as though there is something wrong with the connection string.  do you have the mySQL odbc driver installed?

the easiest way I have found to test connections is to create a text file "New Text Document.txt" and renaming the file extension to udl so you end up with "New Text Document.udl"  then open the file.  It should show you the Datalink proerties wizard.  you can then go through the wizard to create and test the connection.  to get the connection string. either open the ".udl" file with notepad or change the extension back to ".txt" and open it with notepad.

Comment: Do I need to seperately install MySQL ODBC Drivers?

Comment: Installing the MySQL ODBC Drivers Worked for me!! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: This gave a much more accurate connection string than the Visual Studio method, thank you!