# Excel VBA to connect to MySQL on linux server

Tags: mysql, excel, mysql-connector, database-connection, vba

I am trying to connect to MySQL database using VBA from my local machine. The database is in the linux server(XXXX.xxx.edu). I have the SSH client in my machine through which I connect to the *****.xxx.edu server. Once when I login and use the below command, I am able to access the MySQL database without any problem.

mysql  -p -h XXXX.XXX.edu -u username dbname

However,I need to run the VBA in my machine and insert the values into this database. I tried to connect using the code mentioned in the below link.

[Error in VBA:`[Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5455078/error-in-vbamicrosoftodbc-manager-data-source-name-not-found-and-no-defaul?rq=1)

As told in the suggestion of the above link, I installed the MYSQL ODBC drivers which installed the MySQL 5.5 in my machine. Even after installing, I get the error,

[Microsoft][ODBC Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

I am not able to figure out what exactly is the problem. How should I connect to the linux server and then connect to the MySQL database?

Comment: got some ports open or just 22 ?

Comment: well open up 3306 bud

Comment: Yeah. I did that. But still I get the data source name not found error.

Comment: can you see the list of databases in odbc config ?

Comment: How do I check it? I created a text document and saved it in the .udl format. In that datalink file, I see a list of providers like Microsoft OLE Provider. However, I am not sure how to check the databases.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30608/discussion-between-ramesh-and-drew-pierce)

Comment: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/707/out1.gif/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
you install the mysql odbc driver (the msi) from here.
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/
you run ODBC Data Source Administrator
go to System DSN
click Add
select, for instance, MySql ODBC Unicode Driver
click finish.
dns name: fred
description: fred
tcpip server: 192.168.1.11 (whatever, dns, so long as u can point to it)
port 3306
user: root (whatever)
pwd: whatever works
drop down database, click test or view them
```

Comment: I get the error  "The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the driver and the application". I installed the odbc driver from the given link and able to create the data source as mentioned in the above steps. This is the code in my VBA.       `Dim oConn As ADODB.Connection
    Set oConn = New ADODB.Connection
    oConn.Open "ramesh"`

Comment: This worked for me to help connect from Excel into a MySQL database hosted on my Homestead virtual machine